# Differential Equations - How to go from my answer to the book's answer?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

so I'm doing variation of parameters:

$$y'' - y = \frac{1}{e^x + e^{-x}}$$
Let the particular solution be the form of:
$$y_p = u_1y_1 + u_2y_2$$

$$y_1 = e^x$$ $$y_2 = e^{-x}$$

Now we assume $u_1'y_1 + u_2'y_2 = 0$, let's call this equation (1).
$$u_1'e^x + u_2'e^{-x}=0$$
Now we differentiate $y_1$ and $y_2$ to get the next equation, let's call it (2):

$$u_1'e^x - u_2'e^{-x} = \frac{1}{e^x + e^{-x}}$$

Right? So far so good. Now we add both equation (1) and (2) and we can solve for $u_1'$.

$$2u_1'e^x = \frac{1}{e^x + e^{-x}}$$

$$u_1' = \frac{1}{2} \bigg(\frac{1}{e^{2x} + 1}\bigg)$$

After integrating, I end up with $$u_1 = \frac{1}{4}\bigg(-\ln(e^{2x}+1)+2x\bigg)$$

So now I plug in $u_1'$ into either equation (1) or (2) to get $u_2'$ and to solve for $u_2$.

I will plug it into equation (1) since it's easier.

$$\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+1}\bigg) + u_2'e^{-x} = 0$$

$$u_2'e^{-x} = -\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{e^x + e^{-x}}\bigg)$$

$$u_2' = -\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{1 + e^{-2x}}\bigg)$$

Now my professor said to integrate this, we should manipulate the integrand using rules of exponents, but I'm not sure how to do that...

So I just did this:

After integrating, I end up with:

$$\frac{1}{4}\bigg(-\ln(e^{-2x}+1) + \ln(e^{-2x})\bigg)$$

Now I have both $u_1$ and $u_2$, but the problem is I don't know how to get the answer to match the books.

My final answer is:

$$\frac{-\ln(e^{2x}+1)e^x + 2xe^x -\ln(e^{-2x}+1)e^{-x}-2xe^{-x}}{4}$$

The books answer is:

[image]

Is my answer equivalent to the books answer? If so, how can I make it match?

Comment: What did I do wrong? I'm 100% sure I integrated $u_1'$ and $u_2'$ correctly, and then I plugged it in to get the particular solution.

Comment: The solution in the book is correct (you can substitute it into the differential equation and see that the two sides are equal.  This is most easily done using symbolic computation software.)  Therefore, there's an error in your solution.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Just because a book's solution is correct does not mean there isn't another way to represent the answer. Obviously it's going to be correct if you differentiate and plug in. You can't conclude my answer is incorrect without specifying where in which step I went wrong.

Comment: If you substitute your solution into the differential equation, you'll find that it doesn't satisfy the differential equation.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Check your math. The two answers are equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$ \ln(e^{-2x}+1) = \ln(e^{-2x}) + \ln(1+e^{2x}) = -2x + \ln(1+e^{2x}) $$

Therefore
$$ \frac{-e^x\ln(e^{2x}+1) - e^{-x}(-2x + \ln(e^{2x}+1))+2xe^x-2xe^{-x}}{4} \\ = \frac{2xe^x - (e^x+e^{-x})\ln(e^{2x}+1)}{4} $$

Here's an alternate way to integrate (likely what your prof meant)
$$ -\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{e^{-2x}+1}dx = -\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{e^{2x}}{e^{2x}+1}dx = -\frac{1}{4}\ln(e^{2x}+1) $$

Answer (score 2):

**Checking Op's answer**

$$
\begin{align}
Y_p=&\frac{-ln(e^{2x}+1)e^x + 2xe^x -ln(e^{-2x}+1)e^{-x}-2xe^{-x}}{4} \\
=&\frac{-ln(e^{2x}+1)e^x + 2xe^x -ln(e^{2x}+1)e^{-x}+2xe^{-x}-2xe^{-x}}{4} \\
=&\frac{-ln(e^{2x}+1)e^x + 2xe^x -ln(e^{2x}+1)e^{-x}}4 \\
Y_p=&\frac{-(e^x+e^{-x})\ln|(e^{2x}+1)| + 2xe^x }4 \\
\end{align}
$$
It's the same answer as that of the book...

---

***A simple hint***

Not an anwer. Just checking the book's answer in case...

$$y'' - y = \frac{1}{e^x + e^{-x}}$$
$$y''-y'+y' - y = \frac{1}{e^x + e^{-x}}$$
$$g'+g = \frac{1}{e^x + e^{-x}}$$
$$(ge^x)' = \frac{e^x}{e^x + e^{-x}}$$
$$ge^x = \int \frac{e^x}{e^x + e^{-x}}dx$$
$$ge^x = \int \frac{u}{u^2 + 1}du \implies ge^x = \frac 12\int \frac{2u}{u^2 + 1}du=\frac 12 \ln|u^2+1|+K_1$$
$$(ye^{-x})' =e^{-2x}(\frac 12 \ln|e^{2x}+1|+K_1)$$
$$y =K_1e^{-x}+K_2e^{x}+e^{x}\underbrace{\int e^{-2x}(\frac 12 \ln|e^{2x}+1|)dx}_{\text { Integrale }I_2} $$
I evaluated the last integral $I_2$ and got this
$$e^xI_2=\frac {xe^x}2-\frac 14 (e^v+e^{-x})\ln|e^{2x}+1|$$
Therefore
$$\boxed{y =K_1e^{-x}+e^{x}(K_2+\frac {x}2)-\frac 12 \cosh(x)\ln|e^{2x}+1|}$$

Comment: So my answer is correct? Thank you!